# Unproper State of entry after Attach

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm playing over Add/ Attach and struggle with something.

**If in the last rows of my example(in case 2) I get reference to the Entry(entry4) of my entity, the State in every entry instance is changed. But if no entry4(in case 1) the State in every entry is not changed.**

```
var book = new Book
{
    BookId = 3,
    AuthorName = "Andrzej Sapkowski"
};
var entry1 = context.Entry(book); 
// -> entry1.State equals to Detached
var entry2 = context.Attach(book);
// -> entry1.State, entry2.State equal to Unchanged
var entry3 = context.Entry(book); 
// -> entry1.State, entry2.State, entry3.State equal to Unchanged
book.Title = "The witcher 1";
```

**CASE 1(the row is commented)**

```
// var entry4 = context.Entry(book); 
// -> NOTHING changed: entry1.State, entry2.State, entry3.State equal to Unchanged
```

**CASE 2(the row is NOT commented)**

```
var entry4 = context.Entry(book); 
// -> EVERYTHING changed: entry1.State, entry2.State, entry3.State equal to Modified
```

Also

```
entry1!=entry2!=entry3!=entry4
```

***Versions***: **.Net Core 3.1**, **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.1**

So I don't understand how getting a reference can change the State. Even if it is bug it is very,very weird bug. Something is changed through the getter.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think book is already tracked, so after you make the modification to the source, and attempt to attach it, it will see the difference and will mark the entry as modified. Also, entry1.Entity==entry2.Entity==entry3.Entity==entry4.Entity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The book in my case is not tracked. And I don't understand you perfectly. But YES entity instances are same but in different references. I say the entry instances (entry1, entry2, ... ) are different instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the existing EntityEntry objects doesn't change until change tracking runs on the object.  Book is a POCO and so there's no magic way for the change tracker to know you've changed the Title.

Getting a new EntityEntry for the book detects the change, and makes it visible on all the other EntityEntrys.  Or running :

```
book.Title = "The witcher 1";
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
```

Will update the existing EntityEntry objects with the correct state.

Comment: Working. Thanks you! It seems a bit weird in the first touches with EF. So when SaveChanges is called it will internally call DetectChanges. And it keeps reference to the created Entry instances(entry1, entry2, ..) and update them I guess. This update is a the trickiest part.